# Exit and Play button don't register well

Tags: c++, if-statement, sfml

So been trying my exit and play button work but they do not react the way I want them too for some strange reason. When I change one to else if and if only statement they either both exit or change them again and both start the game. They act like they are the same button and not individuals despite how they are selected and pressed.

Here is my header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include "State.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class MainMenu : public Engine::State
{
public:
    enum behavior
    {
        HOVERED, NORMAL
    };
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Context> context;
    sf::Text gameTitle;
    sf::Text playButton;
    sf::Text exitButton;
    void hover(sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::Event event);

    //checking certain conditions if it is true or false
    bool isPlayButtonSelected;
    bool isPlayButtonPressed;
    bool isExitButtonSelected;
    bool isExitButtonPressed;

public:
    
    MainMenu(std::shared_ptr<Context>& context);
    ~MainMenu();

    
    void Init() override;

    void ProcessInput() override;
    void Update(sf::Time deltaTime) override;
    void Draw() override;

};
```

Here is the cpp file:

```
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "GamePlay.h"

MainMenu::MainMenu(std::shared_ptr<Context> &context) : context(context),
isPlayButtonSelected(true), isPlayButtonPressed(false), isExitButtonPressed(false),
isExitButtonSelected(false)
{

}

MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{

}

void MainMenu::Init()
{
    //our assets being put here that we stored and implement it
    context -> assets ->AddFont(MainFont, "Assets/Asdonuts.ttf");

    //Titlle screen name of the game code
    gameTitle.setFont(context->assets->GetFont(MainFont));
    gameTitle.setString("Final Game Project");

    gameTitle.setOrigin(gameTitle.getGlobalBounds().width/2,
                        gameTitle.getGlobalBounds().height/2);

    gameTitle.setPosition(context->window->getSize().x/3.5,
                          context->window->getSize().y/2 - 450.f);
    gameTitle.setCharacterSize(150);

    //This is the code for the play button
    playButton.setFont(context->assets->GetFont(MainFont));
    playButton.setString("Start");

    playButton.setOrigin(playButton.getGlobalBounds().width/2,
                        playButton.getGlobalBounds().height/2);

    playButton.setPosition(context->window->getSize().x/2,
                          context->window->getSize().y/2 - 50.f);
    playButton.setCharacterSize(70);

    //This is the code for the exit button
    exitButton.setFont(context->assets->GetFont(MainFont));
    exitButton.setString("Exit");

    exitButton.setOrigin(exitButton.getGlobalBounds().width/2,
                        exitButton.getGlobalBounds().height/2);

    exitButton.setPosition(context->window->getSize().x/2,
                          context->window->getSize().y/2 + 50.f);
    exitButton.setCharacterSize(70);
}

//this function is when the screen is running and reads user input when pressing
//the buttons and things that happend when they press certain buttons
//while also keeping the window open till they choose to close it on the x button
//on the top right corner
void MainMenu::ProcessInput()
{
    sf::Event event;
    while(context->window->pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            context->window->close();
        }

        else if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            switch(event.key.code)
            {
                case sf::Keyboard::Up:
                {
                    if(!isPlayButtonSelected)
                    {
                        isPlayButtonSelected = true;
                        isExitButtonSelected = false;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case sf::Keyboard::W:
                {
                    if(!isPlayButtonSelected)
                    {
                        isPlayButtonSelected = true;
                        isExitButtonSelected = false;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case sf::Keyboard::Down:
                {
                    if(!isExitButtonSelected)
                    {
                        isPlayButtonSelected = false;
                        isExitButtonSelected = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case sf::Keyboard::S:
                {
                    if(!isExitButtonSelected)
                    {
                        isPlayButtonSelected = false;
                        isExitButtonSelected = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case sf::Keyboard::Enter:
                {
                    isPlayButtonPressed = false;
                    isExitButtonPressed = false;

                    if(!isPlayButtonPressed)
                    {
                        isPlayButtonPressed = true;
                    }

                    else if(!isExitButtonPressed)
                    {
                        isExitButtonPressed = true;
                    }

                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

void MainMenu::Update(sf::Time deltaTime)
{
    //conditions for the menu fonts and all
    //so like we know who is highlighted and not highlighted for the user to understand
    //what is going on and what selection they are hovering on
    if(isPlayButtonSelected)
    {
        playButton.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        exitButton.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    }

    else
    {
        exitButton.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        playButton.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    }

    //important thing for our main menu
    //if Play button is pressed the game starts
    if(isPlayButtonPressed)
    {
        context->states->Add(std::make_unique<GamePlay>(context), true);
    }

    //if the exit button is pressed, the game SHOULD exit
    else if(isExitButtonPressed)
    {
        context->window->close();
    }

}

void MainMenu::Draw()
{
    //draw everything that needs to be display in the main menu
    context->window->clear(sf::Color(53, 189, 164));
    context->window->draw(gameTitle);
    context->window->draw(playButton);
    context->window->draw(exitButton);
    context->window->display();
}
```

So an example what I mean is this one both buttons start the game but if I change it to this:

```
case sf::Keyboard::Enter:
                {
                    isPlayButtonPressed = false;
                    isExitButtonPressed = false;

                    if(!isPlayButtonPressed)
                    {
                        isPlayButtonPressed = true;
                    }

                    if(!isExitButtonPressed)
                    {
                        isExitButtonPressed = true;
                    }

                    break;
                }

if(isPlayButtonPressed)
    {
        context->states->Add(std::make_unique<GamePlay>(context), true);
    }

    //if the exit button is pressed, the game SHOULD exit
    if(isExitButtonPressed)
    {
        context->window->close();
    }
```

They will both exit and not start the game. I have been messing around one if and the other else or both as if statements. Despite the changes and testing none of the buttons act individually and act how they are supposed to act. So curious how to fix this issue?

Unsure if I should provide all my headers and cpp files for more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure if I understand well your problem, but in your example it seems like `isExitButtonPressed` is always true at the end.
You're setting it to false at the begining and then setting it to true in the if statement which has always a fulfilled condition giving the fact that you set `isExitButtonPressed` to false beforehand !